# what is the significance of the equilibrium solution and other solutions in an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question regarding this differential equation here, this is a picture of the direction field. I am kind of confused is it correct that the only solution that is independent of t is the horizontal line at  p = 900? so the line I draw is a solution as well, but it is a solution that depends on both p and t, is it correct?

[image]

It says the equilibrium solution is independent of t. But how about the solution I draw here using the red color? (the red line), I thought this solution and basically all other solutions also depend on t in addition to p, is it correct?

And what's so significance if all other solutions converges to the p = 900 if t goes to infinity? and if they all diverge from p = 900? what is the significance of the observation? (divergence vs convergence when t approaches infinity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the differential equation

$$\dfrac{dp}{dt} = \dfrac{1}{2} p - 450$$

An equilibrium (or equilibrium point) of a dynamical system generated by an autonomous system of ordinary differential equations (ODEs) is a solution that **does not change with time**. Another way of saying this is where the derivative is zero (constant).

To find the equilibrium point(s), we set $p' = 0$, so find $p = 900$.

If we draw a direction field plot of $p'(t)$, it shows a representation of how **all solutions** would behave. We should see a constant zero slope at the equilibrium point.

This **general** direction field plot looks like

[image]

We can see even more solutions in this variant

[image]

Notice that the slope is constants at the equilibrium, $p = 900$, but that above that, it is increasing and below that it is decreasing. Why?

Lets choose two different initial conditions and solve of ODE. The first above the equilibrium and the second below

$$p(0) = 950 \implies p(t) = 50 \left(e^{t/2}+18\right)$$

$$p(0) = 850 \implies p(t) = -50 \left(e^{t/2}-18\right)$$

Lets superimpose those two curves onto the direction field plot (red is the first and green the second)

[image]

What do you notice if you take the limit of each of those results as $t \rightarrow \infty$? This is what is so excellent about a direction field (phase portrait) plot, it shows the general behaviors across all solutions.

Now, what do you get if you solve the ODE for $p(0) = 900$?

You can experiment with this direction filed and phase portrait [*plotter*](https://homepages.bluffton.edu/%7Enesterd/apps/slopefields.html) for more examples (just click anywhere for an IC).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. You said $p^'(t)$ represents all solutions, looking at $dp/dt = \frac{1}{2}t - 450$, I thought it means the slope only depends on p. But when we look at the individual solution, we can see that the slope actually changes with respect to t? is it not?  For example, when I take the derivative of the first solution i.e. $p(t) = 50 (e^{\frac{t}{2}}+18)$, I would have an expression involving t. So the slope actually changes with respect to t, but how comes $\frac{dp}{dt}= \frac{1}{2}p - 450$ doesn't involve t? How come the solution satisfies the given ODE?

Comment: So does it mean the solution is a function of t and p as well? or we consider the individual solution as a function of t only? Or only the slope equation (ODE) is a function of both p and t?  or even this ODE is actually only a function of t only but not p?  I am kind of confused.

Comment: But it seems that it is true the slope of each of the individual solution for a fixed value of p is always the same. Also this seems to be what the ODE $\frac{dp}{dt} = \frac{1}{2}p(t) - 450$ is saying (as function of p only). So all function will have the EXACT same slope value if given the same value of p. Basically the slope is given by the ODE, but the ODE is saying the slope changes with p only. It seems to be the case, since for a given value of p, all solution have the same value of slope (i.e. dp/dt). But however the individual solution is saying the slope changes with p and t.